# ELK and filebeat: matching CSV with mysql before inserting logs

Tags: ubuntu, logging, elastic-stack, filebeat

**The setup:**

I have an Ubuntu 16 server. I've downloaded the ELK stack and configured filebeat to run with logstash. In other words filebeat -> logstash -> elastic. 
(mainly the configuration is that is found [here](http://robwillis.info/2017/04/elk-5-on-ubuntu-pt-2-installing-and-configuring-elasticsearch-logstash-kibana-nginx/))

**The CSV File:**

I have a CSV file similar to:

```
Value1;Value2;Value3;Value4
```

My Logstash Filter is as following:

```
csv {
  separator => ";"
  columns => ["Title1", "Title2", "Title3", "Title4"]
}
```

**The question**

I want to add a "Title5" Column with Value "Value5" fetched from mysql such as:

```
Select Title5 From ValuesTable Where Title1='Value1' AND Title3='Value3'
```

Is this possible? and how would you advise me to do it?

Thanks

Comment: I don't understand.  you want to get "Title5" when you never post it to elastic?

Comment: I want to Post it along with the data. But I don't know how to fetch it from mysql & append it to the posted data.